# Set the date to the next day date in python

Tags: python, python-2.7

I am working on my python code to generate the date format so I can be able to search for the data into the database, example: `20180222010000`.

I have got a bit of trouble with the code that I am currently using because when I run the code, it should have adding the date to the next day date when I set the `self.program_day` to day `1` from `0` when my current time show between 21:00 to 06:00. On my code it will only show the same day date, example: today date is 22 so if I set `self.program_day` to 1 then it will still show today date 22 which it should have been 23. If I want to set the date to the next day, I would have to fire my code again so I can be able to add each day date to the 24, 25, 26 and so on after when I have to run my code twice.

Here is the code:

```
def get_next_day(self, time_string):
    to_datetime = datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(time.mktime(time.strptime(time_string, '%Y%m%d')))
    nextday = to_datetime + datetime.timedelta(days = self.program_day)
    return nextday.strftime('%Y%m%d')

next_day = time.strftime("%Y%m%d")
next_day = self.get_next_day(next_day)
get_minutes = time.strftime("%M")
next_day = str(next_day)
program_start_date = ''

if self.program_day == 5 and int(get_hour) >= 20 and int(get_hour) <= 23:
   pass
else:
   self.program_day += 1

for channels in channels_list:
    if str(get_hour) == '00':
       program_start_date = str(next_day + '00' + get_minutes + '00')
    elif str(get_hour) == '01':
       program_start_date = str(next_day + '01' + get_minutes + '00')
    elif str(get_hour) == '02':
       program_start_date = str(next_day + '02' + get_minutes + '00')
    elif str(get_hour) == '03':
       program_start_date = str(next_day + '03' + get_minutes + '00')
    elif str(get_hour) == '04':
        program_start_date = str(next_day + '04' + get_minutes + '00')
    elif str(get_hour) == '05':
       program_start_date = str(next_day + '05' + get_minutes + '00')
    elif str(get_hour) == '06':
       program_start_date = str(next_day + '06' + get_minutes + '00')
    elif str(get_hour) == '07':
       program_start_date = str(next_day + '07' + get_minutes + '00')
    elif str(get_hour) == '08':
       program_start_date = str(next_day + '08' + get_minutes + '00')
    elif str(get_hour) == '09':
       program_start_date = str(next_day + '09' + get_minutes + '00')
    elif str(get_hour) == '10':
       program_start_date = str(next_day + '10' + get_minutes + '00')
    elif str(get_hour) == '11':
       program_start_date = str(next_day + '11' + get_minutes + '00')
    elif str(get_hour) == '12':
       program_start_date = str(next_day + '12' + get_minutes + '00')
    elif str(get_hour) == '13':
       program_start_date = str(next_day + '13' + get_minutes + '00')
    elif str(get_hour) == '14':
       program_start_date = str(next_day + '14' + get_minutes + '00')
    elif str(get_hour) == '15':
       program_start_date = str(next_day + '15' + get_minutes + '00')
    elif str(get_hour) == '16':
       program_start_date = str(next_day + '16' + get_minutes + '00')
    elif str(get_hour) == '17':
       program_start_date = str(next_day + '17' + get_minutes + '00')
    elif str(get_hour) == '18':
       program_start_date = str(next_day + '18' + get_minutes + '00')
    elif str(get_hour) == '19':
       program_start_date = str(next_day + '19' + get_minutes + '00')
    elif str(get_hour) == '20':
       program_start_date = str(next_day + '20' + get_minutes + '00')
    elif str(get_hour) == '21':
       program_start_date = str(next_day + '21' + get_minutes + '00')
    elif str(get_hour) == '22':
       program_start_date = str(next_day + '22' + get_minutes + '00')
    elif str(get_hour) == '23':
       program_start_date = str(next_day + '23' + get_minutes + '00')

    print "program_start_date for......................next_day"
    print program_start_date
```

Here is the program_start_date:

```
program_start_date for......................next_day
20180222003000
program_start_date for......................next_day
20180222003000
program_start_date for......................next_day
20180222003000
program_start_date for......................next_day
20180222003000
program_start_date for......................next_day
20180222003000
program_start_date for......................next_day
20180222003000
program_start_date for......................next_day
20180222003000
```

What I am trying to achieve is I want to set up the `next_day` date to something is like `20180223`. I have to use the if statements so I can set up the date, time and minutes to make it to show like `20180222010000`.

Can you please show me an example how I can set to the next day date when I am using with `next_day` variable?

Comment: I would recommend you to utilize built in libraries, e.g. https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html. Once you have the date time object you will be able to add days easily.

Comment: @anmaxvl the submitter is using `datetime` and `timedelta` built-ins. Perhaps a [Minimal, Complete and Verifiable Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) would make it easier for folks to help out.

Comment: My bad for not reading it properly.

Answer (score 1):

```
from datetime import datetime
from dateutil.relativedelta import relativedelta

date_now = datetime.now().date()
start_date = date_now + relativedelta(days=+1)
```

This will be allow and success. I test it in python3.

Hope its help you